# Laravel не отображает ошибки валидации форм

Tags: laravel, валидация

У меня случилась проблема с отображением ошибок форм и я не знаю в какой момент это произошло.
Делал проект и все было нормально. Сейчас на сайт добавляю еще одну форму и столкнулся с проблемой что ошибки не выводятся, но при этом валидация проходит.
Проверил другие формы которые ранее работали нормально и выводили ошибки и old(), но сейчас и там это не работает.
Помогите с решением проблемы пожалуйста, я не понимаю как вообще сейчас искать проблему?

Нашел инфу что в файле kernel.php в группе middlewares web должно присутствовать StartSession и ShareErrorsFromSession

Проверил, у меня подключено

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Разобрался методом тыка. Установил laravel чистый и по кусочкам переносил проект и сразу проверил возникает данная ошибка или нет. Проблему нашел в файле kernel.php в массиве $middleware тоже был подключен \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class, и за этого вывод ошибок не работал